# How can I retrieve nested values in Keystone 5 for my list

Tags: keystonejs

I'm adding a list called 'tourlocation' to my Keystone 5 project. In my mongo database my tourlocations collection has an object called 'coordinates', with two values: 'lat' and 'long'. Example:

```
 "coordinates" : {
                "lat" : 53.343761,
                "long" : -6.24953
        },
```

In the previous version of keystone, I could define my tourlocation list coordinates object like this:

```
 coordinates: {
    lat: {
      type: Number,
      noedit: true
    },
    long: {
      type: Number,
      noedit: true
    }
```

Now unfortunately, when I try to define the list this way it gives the error: The `'tourlocation.coordinates' field doesn't specify a valid type. (tourlocation.coordinates.type is undefined)'`

Is there any way to represent objects in keystone 5?

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Hughes I believe your error says "type" which you may need to add it like this

```
keystone.createList('User', {
  fields: {
    name: { type: Text }, // Look at the type "Text" even in the MongoDB you can choose the type but it will be better to choose it here from the beginning.
    email: { type: Text },
  },
});
```

Note that `noedit: true` is not supported in version 5 of KeystoneJS.
For more info look at this page https://www.keystonejs.com/blog/field-types#core-field-types